# Why isn't symlink in application being found in $PATH in OSX?

Tags: macos, environment-variables, symlink, bash

I've always been a little wobbly on OSX environment variables, but I figured that, so long as `/usr/local/bin` was in my `$PATH`, that everything residing in that folder would be usable as a command in the shell.

This doesn't appear to be happening. `$ echo $PATH` gives me:

> /Users/[username]/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

My `/usr/local/bin` folder contains a symlink to an application; let's call it `some-application`. But typing `some-application` in the shell yields the classic bash error:

> -bash: some-application: command not found

Comment: Is the executable flag set on the script file?

Comment: @glglgl permissions are `lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   64 18 Feb 12:05 some-application` (so yes)

Comment: @shennen Are these the flags on the symbolic link or on the script file?

Comment: @glglgl Thanks for the help but I've found the answer. It wasn't an executable issue. See Answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a simple mistake on my part. I had created the symlink using a bad link location:

```
$ ln -s /some/non-existent/location/some-application /usr/local/bin/some-application
```

There was no error on creating this 'link'. The symlink name was the one used in the bash error, masking the fact that it couldn't find the original location, not the link.

For me, I would have either expected an error to be thrown on creation of the link, or at least for bash to detail which path couldn't be resolved. Something like this:

> -bash: /some/non-existent/location/some-application: No such file or directory

Oh well. Case closed.

**P.S**

Any light being shed on why it behaves this way might be helpful to myself and others.